# Ajax with ViewComponent

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

How to use AJAX for ViewComponent in Asp.Net Core? That is calling the method  `@Component.Invoke ("ComponentName", SomeData);` ViewComponent will involve various views depending on `SomeData` without rebooting the main view.

**Update**

My solution is:

```
$(function () {
      $(Container).load('ControllerName/ControllerAction', {
                ArgumentName: ArgumentValue });
                                                 });
```

Controller :

```
public IActionResult ControllerAction(string value)
        {
           return ViewComponent("ViewComponent", value);
        }
```

Is there a way to directly use a ViewComponent as AjaxHelpers in previous versions?

Answer (score 19):

Your solution is correct. [From the docs:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

> [ViewComponents are] not reachable directly as an HTTP endpoint, they're invoked from your code (usually in a view). A view component never handles a request.
>
> While view components don't define endpoints like controllers, you can easily implement a controller action that returns the content of a ViewComponentResult.

So as you suggested, [a lightweight controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.1#invoking-a-view-component-directly-from-a-controller) can act as an AJAX proxy to our ViewComponent.

```
public class MyViewComponentController : Controller 
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get(int id) 
    {
        return ViewComponent("MyViewComponent", new { id });
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on why you would do this? Is it beneficial over just returning the view component's view?

Comment: What do you mean by "return the view component's view" @MichielCornille? Can you give an example of how you might do that. That would help me understand your question.

Comment: MyViewComponent has a Default.cshtml file, and a ViewModel? So you could return those with return PartialView(...) instead of rendering the view component entirely.

Comment: If that works with an AJAX call, then off the top of my head, I do not see an advantage of the one approach over the other. That said, it has been months since I last looked at view components @MichielCornille.

Comment: @Michiel Cornille would you mind putting together an example? I can't imagine any way that would work with AJAX, not without Blazor interop

Comment: I'm in the same situation. The only options seem to be shoving the code into a controller or using a view component in a weird way. I'm not sure it's worth trying to make a view component fit here, it certainly isn't as organized but it's just not possible to truly wire an ajax call up to a viewcomponent.

Comment: In this situation, he must use PartialView Instead, because it already took time for ajax get